# jQuery dialog - won't append to form

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog

I'm more than familiar with the trick of appending a jQuery Dialog div to a form element after having set it to visible. I've done this a hundred or so times in .NET and it works just fine! However, I'm trying to do it on a Coldfusion website, and this is a first for me and it's not working as it should (ie - it's not being appended to the form element). I've verified this through Firebug, so I can see that the jQuery Dialog div is outside of the form element.

Here's my jQuery code:

```
if ($) {
  $(document).on("click", '#btnUpload', function ($e) {

    // Show the jquery dialog plugin
    var dlg = $('#divUpload').dialog({ modal: true, title: 'Photo/Image Upload', draggable: true, width: 700 });

    dlg.parent.appendTo($("form:first"));

    $e.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

and here's my HTML/Coldfusion:

```
<form id="wtf" action="<cfoutput>#cgi.script_name#</cfoutput>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="btnUpload" name="btnUpload" value="Upload Image" />

    <div id="divUpload" style="display: none;">
        <br />
        File to upload:  
        <br />
        <input type="file" name="fileName" size="50" />
        <br /><br />

        <input type="submit" name="UploadFile" value="Upload" />    
    </div>

</form>
```

**EDIT:**
I've also tried

```
dlg.parent.appendTo($('#wtf'));
```

but to no avail. Note that the form has an ID attribute of 'wtf'. And yes, the 'wtf' is purely out of frustration at the moment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the `closing quote` of the selector.

Change

```
 dlg.parent.appendTo($("form:first));
```

To

```
 dlg.parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
```

As parent of dlg would be form to which you want to append. You may need to re-consider of you need parent of dlg to append.

```
 dlg.appendTo($("form:first"));
```

Comment: Bah, sorry, it's not that. I had changed the code to try something else just before I posted my question, and then I realized halfway through posting my question that I needed to change it back, and so I just fat-fingered it and left off the ending double quote.

Comment: I think you need dlg.parent() instead of dlg.parent, check my updated answer.